# array.contains runtime in terms of size of array type

Tags: java, arrays, memory, language-agnostic, contains

Say I have two arrays of equal length, one of type x and the other of type y, with x being half the size in memory of y.  If I generated 2 objects, one of type x and the other of type y, and checked to see if their respective arrays contained them, would both operations take, on average, the same time?
Can this time be improved by using another (ordered) data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My systems professor answered this:

> If the work time is bounded on the number of instructions, then the exhaustive searches on the two arrays yield equal time.
>
> If the work time is bounded on the memory access speed, then search on the larger array (here "larger" means more bytes) takes more time.
>
> Whether the work time is instruction-bound or memory access-bound may depend on the compiler.  A poor compiler may produce many instructions such that the time is instruction-bound.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a given element in unordered array has `O(n)` complexity, which means that it's linearly dependent on the number of elements. **It's not dependent on the element's size**, since arrays have constant random access time (the address of n-th element in an array can be calculated using easy pointer arithmetic).

So yes, searching for the 2 objects would take, on average, the same time. Or to be more precise - have the same complexity (linear).

Searching through an ordered data structure such as sorted list or a binary tree allows for using an `O(log (n))` algorithm (binary search), which is, on average, much faster.

Refer to [this cheatsheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) to see some common data structures and the complexities of operations performed on them.

Comment: Unfortunately for this application, I need to have an ordered (not ordered in the sense that data is increasing or decreasing, but in the sense that the data is in a particular order and MUST stay in this order) data structure.  For example, I have one large array and one small array, and I want to see if the smaller one is contained in the larger one in the same order.  I know the complexity of searching through various data structures, I wanted to know the complexity of comparing 2 objects in memory.

Answer (score 0):

use hash-table/hash-set. expected or estimated lookup is `O(1)` assuming comparing two objects is `O(1)`.

but in general, 2x bigger object may require 2x more time to compare. however it doesn't affect array lookup time because during that operation you use an index, not the object itself

Comment: In my use case, data in it must be ordered.  But the second part of your answer is equivalent to what I was asking, thanks!